# Using Got, JEST and Typescript, getting nexpected token error

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, node.js-got

Here is the code, let's call it mycode.ts:

```
import { Tracer } from 'dd-trace';
import got from 'got';
....
export class MyClass {...}
```

And then in test, let call it mycode.test.ts, I just load the file

```
import { MyClass } from './mycode';
```

I get the following error:

> ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import create from './create.js';
> ^^^^^^
> Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token
...
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  1 | import { Tracer } from 'dd-trace';
> 2 | import got from 'got';
    | ^
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score -1):

use this instead

```
const got = require('got');
```

---

and then

```
got.yourfunctionhere
```

---

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: **"transform": {
     "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest"
 }** add this to your jest config file and see if it works